# Concerning $m_1m_2=-1$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, geometry

Given two straight lines $$y=m_1x+c$$ and $$y=m_2x+d$$

When two lines are perpendicular to each other the product of their gradients, $m_1m_2=-1.$

How can I show that $$m_1m_2=-1?$$

Comment: How do you define perpendicular?  ... since that's what we have to show.

Comment: crossing each other at right angle in a plane

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $l_1$ denote the first line $y = m_1x+c$, and let $l_2$ denote the second line $y = m_2x+d$. Whether these two lines are perpendicular or not depends only on their slopes, so in the following, we may set $c=d=0$.

Let $P=(x_1,y_1)$ and $Q=(x_2,y_2)$ be two points on the line $l_1$. Then
$$m_1 = \frac{y_2-y_1}{x_2-x_1}.$$
Assume that the two lines are perpendicular. Then $P' = (-y_1,x_1)$ and $Q'=(-y_2,x_2)$ are points on the line $l_2$ (the points have been rotated $90^{\circ}$ counter-clockwise about the origin).

The slope of line $l_2$ is then seen to be
$$m_2 = \frac{x_2-x_1}{-y_2-(-y_1)}=\frac{x_2-x_1}{y_1-y_2} = -1/m_1.$$
Thus
$$m_1m_2 = -1.$$

Comment: Whether $P'$ and $Q'$ are on $l_2$ depends on the values of $c$ and $d$.

Comment: @mzp, you are right. I will modify my solution.

Answer (score 2):

By direction vectors

- $y=m_1x+c\implies v=(1,m_1)$
- $y=m_2x+c\implies w=(1,m_2)$

then by dot product

$$v\cdot w = 1+m_1m_2=0\implies m_1m_2=-1$$

Or as an alternative

- $m_1= \tan \theta_1$
- $m_2= \tan \theta_2=\tan (\theta_1+\pi/2)= -\cot \theta_1=-\frac 1 {\tan \theta_1}$

then

$$m_1m_2=\tan \theta_1\left(-\frac 1 {\tan \theta_1}\right)=-1$$

Comment: Can you by any chance show it using general secondary school maths, and not using vector?

Comment: @GiantLeap I've added the derivation by $m=\tan \theta$.

Comment: ok fair enough, I accept

Answer (score 0):

The angle $\theta$ between 2 lines is given by 
$$\tan(\theta)=|\frac{m_1-m_2}{1+m_1m_2}|$$
Suppose $m_1m_2\ne -1$, then $\tan(\theta)$ is defined and hence $\theta$ is not $90^{\circ}$ which is a contradiction. Thus we must have $m_1m_2=-1$.

Comment: @Landuros one could go by contradiction. Suppose $m_1m_2 \ne -1$, then the angle between the points is not $90^{\circ}$

Answer (score 0):

Think about rotating line $y=m_1x+c$ 90° clockwise about the origin. This will result in $x$ becoming $-y$ and $y$ becoming $x$ so the equation of the rotated line will be $-x=m_1y+c$ or $y=-\frac{1}{m_1}x-\frac{c}{m_1}$.

Answer (score 0):

Similar to Gimusi's answer, hopefully a bit different :

$y=m_1x +c_1$, or

$m_1x -y+c_1=0$.

Normal to $f(x,y) = m_1x-y +c_1=0:$

$\vec n = (m_1, -1,0)$

Line with direction vector $\vec n$:

$\vec r (t) =t \vec n + \vec r_0$.

Let $\vec r_0=(0,0,0)$.

$x(t)= t m_1, y(t)= -t1 $.

$y = -x/m_1.$